# Remove header from the page after TOC and LOF

Tags: header-footer, lyx, koma-script, fancyhdr

I am using Koma-script book document class, twosides, and I also use the package `\fancyhdr` to modify my pages.

The problem is that header appears both in the next page after TOC and after LOF, so I wonder if there a way to remove the header from these pages

Comment: I tried to use '\fancyhead{}', but this command just removed the name from the header. What actually I want is the pages after TOC and LOF to be completely empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this code snippet many, many years ago from I don't remember where, so unfortunately I can't credit its originator; but it certainly isn't mine.

```
\makeatletter \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
\ifodd\c@page\else \hbox{} \vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi} \makeatother
```

All this really does is redefine `\cleardoublepage` to include `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but this will do what you want (if I'm interpreting what you want correctly).  It will also remove headers and footers from any page that's cleared by `\cleardoublepage`; e.g., blank verso pages at the end of a chapter.

Comment: @dgoomaniii Thank you very much!!!! It worked!!! Since I use LyX I include the code above the TOC

Comment: Actually, either, but it makes more sense in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something to change the defaults of `scrbook` (see the example below).

To ensure that the blank pages after TOC and LOF are empty insert

```
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=empty}
```

at the end of your preamble or at the very beginning of the document.

---

Here is an example to show that with `scrbook` the blank page after TOC is in the default empty:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```