# Remove the header in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am writing a maths book for A level students using the class `book`, and I am completely new to LaTeX, so please bear with me if this is trivial. I have written a simplified version of my code down here. When I execute it, there is a blank page with the fancy header with the horizontal bar. How can make the header blank? I think the whole *CONTENTS* and then *CONTENTS* again thing looks rather silly.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\title{First Year Pure Mathematics}
\author{Luke Collins and Sandro Grech}
\date{}
\fancypagestyle{front}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}        
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{front}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
text
\chapter{How to use this book}
text

\mainmatter
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{Logical Foundation}
    rest of book
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\thispagestyle` for specific page. in this case you can write `\thispagestyle{empty}` in the page that you want ...

Comment: Always use `\cleardoublepage` before changing `\pagestyle` (but `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` issue it). In my opinion the table of contents should be in the front matter, particularly if it uses the same page style as in the front matter. Also avoid `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, you'll regret it if you add `hyperref`; better removing the page number by applying a suitable page style. You may want to consider loading  `emptypage` for making completely empty pages added by `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of the following:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246505/remove-header-from-the-page-after-toc-and-lof  However, I'm not flagging as a duplicate because Werner's answer gives a lot of great information that the other thread doesn't.  In other words, the question is a duplicate; but the answer adds a lot of value.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually due to an incorrect use of your timing in setting the `\pagestyle`.

Since the ToC is set under the `front` page style, and the main document should be processed under `main`, you should use

```
\chapter{Logical foundation}
\pagestyle{main}
```

rather than the other way around. That is, you chapter is first set (the heading; this actually includes a `\cleardoublepage` to start on an odd page under the `book` class), *then* you set the page style to be `main`.

---

In the hypothetical instance where you have a non-empty page style (header) as part of the ToC, you can issue the following to ensure a purely blank page (if it exists) at the end of the ToC:

```
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\fi
```

`\clearpage` makes sure you move to the next page where you then check whether you're on an odd/even page. If you're on an even page (the false clause when checking `\ifodd\value{page}`), then issue `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

The `empty` page style has no header or footer. Of course, you can create a new page style for such pages. The above is just an example of how to manage that.

Answer (score 3):

A little too late, but I found a working solution, apply `\pagestyle{empty}` before the TOC and restore it to `\pagestyle{fancy}` afterwards:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

---

If you need to remove/change the whitespace that remains on the header area when applying \pagestyle{empty}, you can apply a new geometry and then restore it afterwards:

```
%You can choose your values for the margins.

\newgeometry{top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\restoregeometry
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

---

There's no need to use \newpage as \restoregeometry already applies \pagebreak

Answer (score 0):

This is works...

```
% REMOVE HEADER CONTENTS
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

Comment: Please do not only post a snippet of code out of context but integrate it into a MWE and explain why it works.